# How do I change the frame continuation counter from roman numerals (i, ii, iii, ...) to arabics ( 1,2,3, ...)?

Tags: beamer, frame-title, beamer-metropolis

I'm trying to find my way through a metropolis-themed template, and I'm kind of lost. I'd love to replace those lowercase roman numerals that appear in multipaged frames with standard arabic numbers.

I have tried to find a solution within the metropolis documentation, and what seems to come close is the following snippet in section 8.3.4 - Frametitle:

```
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle continuation}{%
\usebeamerfont{frametitle}
\romannumeral \insertcontinuationcount
}
```

The following example reproduces the effect I do *NOT* wish to achieve, as replacing \romannumeral with \arabic produces only 0s als subframe counters.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{metropolis}
\begin{document}

% OPTIONAL PART, UNCOMMENT TO ACTIVATE
%\setbeamertemplate{frametitle continuation}{%
%\usebeamerfont{frametitle}
%\arabic\insertcontinuationcount
%}

  \section{First Section}
  \begin{frame}[allowframebreaks, fragile]{First Frame}
    \begin{itemize}
    \item Hello, world!
    \framebreak
    \item Hello, world again!
    \end{itemize}
  \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Thanks a lot in advance ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can read in the manual, the standard for `\insertcontinuationcount` is to include an arabic number. Therefore you can just set the beamertemplate `frametitle continuation` as: `\setbeamertemplate{frametitle continuation}{\usebeamerfont{frametitle}\insertcontinuationcount}`.

So the complete solution would be

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{metropolis}
\begin{document}

\setbeamertemplate{frametitle continuation}{\usebeamerfont{frametitle}\insertcontinuationcount}

  \section{First Section}
  \begin{frame}[allowframebreaks, fragile]{First Frame}
    \begin{itemize}
    \item Hello, world!
    \framebreak
    \item Hello, world again!
    \end{itemize}
  \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

and your result:

[image]

Comment: This works exactly as I wanted it to!